# Scheduling Jobs - Software Development

Tags: windows, linux, software-development, sql-server, scheduling

I require a free tool (capable to be mantain or grow up with my own developments) to maintain, monitor and schedule [cron jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) that run on Windows, Linux, and executes MSSQL SSIS and MSSQL commands.

These are some functions that I need mandatory:

- Monitoring
- Scheduling dependencies (on successful, on error, etc)
- Alerts
- Log of the output (if a console job has an output, I need that log)

Comment: I think it might be easier to search for two tools, one for each o/s. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: @Mawg didn't think it, yes, of course! Thanks for your comment.